# I'd like to have a "B" in the header for the bibliography similar to the "A" for appendix (classicthesis)

Tags: sectioning, classicthesis

In classicthesis, the Appendix gets a eulerchapternumber formatted "A" at the start.  For consistency, I'd like to add this for the bibliography too.  Is there a way to do this manually without turning the bibliography into a chapter?

Comment: `classicthesis` is a strange package. A guess from my side: `tocbibind` package could help here, but I without seeing any code (and you're a member for more than 3 years now and don't know how to provide a MWE apparently :-( ) from your side, it remains a guess only.

Comment: The “A” doesn't stand for “Appendix”, it's just the first letter of the alphabet. If you have a second `\chapter` in the appendix, it will be marked “B”.

Answer (score 4):

If you have

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
```

you get “A” because this is the first chapter in the appendices and appendices use alphabetical numbering.

It's not very difficult to get “B” for the bibliography: just make it follow the (single) appendix and change the relevant command to issue `\chapter` instead of `\chapter*`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\bib@heading}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}

This is just for citing: \cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]